# Lambda functions passing by reference

Tags: c++, lambda

The lambda function is passed to a gui class and then executed when gui is triggered. When I run the algorithm the first time everything is good then when the gui triggers the lambda the application fails.

I have the following code:

```
RenderObject* renObj = m_geometry[(size_t)ObjectType::plant];
PlaneAlg alg(renObj);
alg.run();

PlaneConfig& config = alg.getConfig();

auto configSetter = [&](double d) {
    config.threshold = d;
    alg.run();
};
QFrame* frame = gui.makeSpinLabel("Threshold: ", 0.1, config.threshold, configSetter);
```

When ever the Lambda function is executed the config and alg variables are shown as not initialized. I am very confused because I thought I have taken care of it by adding & between the brackets.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your code doesn't invoke the lambda? ...

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: @WhiZTiM It does. I just did not put that part because I am trying to keep the code small. I will add if it helps you.

Comment: @Illia, then you are probably having lifetime issues.... Please post an MCVE as Vittorio said.

Comment: @WhiZTiM Yes, as other people mentioned it is the exact problem. Thank for your input.

Comment: I disagree with @VittorioRomeo. I have a complicated gui system written and I believe there is no need to display all the details to solve this question. As it was shown on practice. The downgrade of the question, I think, is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say "*The lambda function is passed to a gui class and then executed when gui is triggered*".

If this is the case then that would mean that a lambda that takes `alg` and `config` as reference would outlive the scope of those 2 variables. The moment the lambda is invoked and tries to access the references they're dangling references and you have Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

```
PlaneAlg alg(renObj);
```

This is an object with automatic storage duration.

> The lambda function is passed to a gui class and then executed when gui is triggered.

That sounds a lot like you're using the lambda as a callback. Am I right to assume that the function creating the lambda goes on similar to the following?

```
gui.on_what_ever (configSetter);
// some code
return /*what ever*/;
```

If so then the `alg` object is going out of scope here, which ends its lifetime. Any reference to it (or to any sub-objects) is then invalid and must not be used, otherwise this leads to undefined behavior.

To solve this you need to make sure the `alg` object stays alive as long as the lambda might be using it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was the exact problem.

Comment: Would accept yours as well but Gill Bates was first. Thanks again Daniel.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you :)